# How to remove or disable case changer button from keyboard in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

i'm designing login and signUp screen for `email-field` i want restrict user to write `Uppercase` characters in textField.

[image]

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if (string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters) != nil) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

This code worked fine for input restriction.

But i want that user can't type it from keybord. For keybord i'm using `IQKeyboardManagerSwift`.

Please give me some solution for this.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
textfield.autocorrectionType = .no
textField.spellCheckingType = .no
```

Then:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: .uppercaseLetters) {
      // Don't allow upper case letters
      return false
   }
 return true
}
```